# I want Bitbucket cloud merge button to trigger Bamboo cloud build

Tags: bamboo, bitbucket-server

So I have builds being triggered by bamboo when there's a push to a branch using the Remote Trigger. This works perfectly.

However, I want the same thing to happen when I click the "merge" button on Bitbucket Server.  The code merges into master but the build does not get triggered.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Http Request Post Receive Hook for this .  https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/de.aeffle.stash.plugin.stash-http-get-post-receive-hook/server/overview

For Bitbucket cloud,
You can select Create New Plan Branches for New Branches under Branches->'Automatic branch management'.  I just tested it on Bitbucket and Bamboo cloud and it works perfectly.

Comment: Thank you, but that plugin does not work with Bitbucket Cloud.

Comment: Thank you.. I'll update my question to include cloud.

Comment: So, that's what I currently have.  I also have a remote trigger in the trigger section. This works fine for pushes to any branch.   The issue is in Bitbucket Cloud when I merge a branch to master.  Master doesn't get triggered for a build.  I kind of temp solve it by doing repository polling.  Doesn't seem like a correct way though.

Comment: If this solution works, then please accept this answer.

Comment: configure plan for master branch. You will not have this problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103028/discussion-between-dhumketu-and-ryan-knopp).